# subscriberView Muito lento ou travado react-native-opentok

Tags: react, react-native

Estou usando o react-native-opentok do callstakio, quando utilizo apenas o Subscriber ele funciona normal, mas quando utilizado subscriber+publisher
o subscriber não funciona corretamente.

```
render() {

    return (
        <View>

           <SubscriberView
              apiKey={OPENTOK_API_KEY}
              sessionId={SESSION_ID}
              token={PUBLISHER_TOKEN}
              style={{ width: x, height: y-200}}
          />

          <PublisherView
              apiKey={OPENTOK_API_KEY}
              sessionId={SESSION_ID}
              token={PUBLISHER_TOKEN}
              style={{ width: x, height: 200}}
          />
        </View>

    );
}

}
```

Comment: Tens um `}` a mais... é para fechar a classe? Algum erro na consola?

Comment: Esse } a mais veio sobrando é o que fecha a classe.
O problema é que o subscriber trava ou fica muito lento depois de alguns segundos de uso

Comment: É preciso ver mais do código... o que colocaste diz pouco, nem sabemos de onde vem o `x`, `y` etc...